# How to make alarm initiate even after restart device?

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarm

How to make my calendar events alarm wake up even after restarting the mobile? (i.e) if the current time is 10am; i'm setting alarm for 10.05am and now(10am) if i restart my device, the alarm should ring on 10.05am. How to achieve it? I have already created alarm for my calendar events. But if i restart my device, the alarm is ringing once i restarted itself. But all other queued alarms are cancelled. Any Help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: are you referring to Calendar Reminders Alarm (of an event about to happend), or built-in OS Alarm (e.g. those that wake you from bed)

Comment: I'm referring Calendar's Reminder alarm. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Put `"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"` as an intent filter in a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: I'm using following code in manifest:
<receiver android:name="android.todoapplication.AlarmReceiver" android:exported="true">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can  use BroadCaste Reciever, becuase device gets a broadcaste when device switched

on, so you can register for that broadcaste and in its reciever you can schedule your alarm..

here is an example how you can do it, http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

Answer (score 2):

Put "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" as an intent filter in a BroadcastReceiver, then you can receive the phone being powered on and schedule the alarm.